Does early return of the same variable prevent NRVO?
Here is the code:
std::vector<int> foo(bool cond) {
    std::vector<int> result;
    if (cond) {
        return result;      // (1)
    }
    result.push_back(42);
    return result;          // (2)
}

The same variable result is being returned from two places. Is that still considered as a condition for NRVO?
P.S. I realize that this code can be refactored to return this value from a single point, so my question is theoretical.
Update: Ok, NRVO is optional even in C++17. Is there any reason why multiple returns would prevent the compiler to use NRVO but the optimization would be used for a single return?

AFAIK there is no language rule to prevent it.  "Will it happen?", that depends on the compiler, optimizations, and target platform.

You can test it on your preferred compilers by replacing the vector with your own class with logging in copy/move constructors.

@NathanOliver, I'm interested whether that is still considered as NRVO (thus mandatory since C++17) or an optional optimization.


Does early return of the same variable prevent NRVO?

No, NRVO is still possible and most implementations will indeed use it in this situation.

I understand that it is "still possible". I'm interested in C++17: if I understand correctly, since this version NRVO is mandatory. So it is either NRVO or a "non-NRVO possible extension".

@DmitryKuzminov NRVO isn't mandatory in C++17 even if there's only one return statement.

@DmitryKuzminov There is no mandatory NRVO in any C++ version.

@DmitryKuzminov The point interjay made is that it wouldn't be mandatory even if there was only one return.

@DmitryKuzminov C++17 RVO is mandatory, NRVO is optional see Copy elision

@DmitryKuzminov mandatory copy elision in C++17 is only for prvalues (usually temp objects).
